# 英語環境のMacでGoogle IMEを使い ¥ を入力する方法

Tags: macos, rubymine

OS Xで Google IMEを使い `¥`のキーで`\`が入力されるように設定してるのですが、
RubyMineでは`¥`が入力されてしまいます。

キーボードカスタマイズツールを使って対策をされている方の記事は見つかったのですが、RubyMineのバグだと思いIssuesに登録しました。
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-144798

ですが英語環境では、恐らくキー配列の違いが原因だと思いますが、そもそもGoogleIMEの英数入力モードで円記号が入力されないようです。

再現しないことにはバグ対策は取られないでしょうし、何か再現するための手段はないでしょうか？
日本語で質問したほうが方法を知ってる人がいるかと思いここに質問させていただきました。

### 追記

「¥キーで入力する文字」に円記号を設定していてもアプリによってはバックスラッシュが入力される事がわかりました。私の環境では iTerm では常にバックスラッシュが入力されます。

Google IMEの英数モードを使っている時に iTerm で円記号を入力する方法を教えて下さい。

Comment: ASCIIコードでは、\= 0x5cです。JISで、半角yen マークは、0x5cです。
UTF-8では、別のコードが半角yenでしょう。まず、テキストエディタで、Google IMEが、0x5cを書いているか、確認しましたか？

Comment: 確認方法があっているかわからないのですが、コンソール上で`pry`を使い`"\\".ord.to_s(16)`とした所 "5c" が確認できました。ただ、「¥を使う」モードでもコンソール上ではバックスラッシュが、Chromeのアドレス欄では円記号が入力されたのでアプリの言語設定によっても変化するようです。

Answer (score 1):

optionキー併用で入力できませんか？

Comment: 具体的にはどのキーと同時入力すれば良いのでしょうか？

Comment: Option + Yですけど？

Comment: 円マーク（バックスペース）はOptionキー併用でトグル入力できたと思う。
Optionなし(単独)でどちらの入力にするかはIMやエディタの設定次第。
CotEditorとかには設定項目があったと思う。
GoogleIMEは使ってなかったのでわかりません。

Comment: @Harawo ありがとうございます Option + Y で円記号を入力できたのですが、iTermなど恐らく環境設定が英語になってるソフト上ではバックスラッシュが入力されてしまうようです。そのようなソフト上で円記号を入力する方法はありますか？

Comment: @かぼちゃ頭 Optionキーでトグルで来たんですね知りませんでした。ただ、上記レスや追記でも書きましたようにiTermなどのアプリ上では上手く動かず全てバックスラッシュになってしまいました。

Answer (score 0):

> Google IMEの英数モードを使っている時に iTerm で円記号を入力する方法を教えて下さい。

ターミナルでも円記号を入力できません。Option+Yとキーを打つと、バックスラッシュが入力されます。おそらくiTermは、ターミナルのこの挙動に準拠しているのだと推測できます。
IMEは、Google IMEかどうかは関係ありません。システム環境設定で、入力ソースをU.S.にして入力しても、円記号はバックスラッシュになります。

> iTermなど恐らく環境設定が英語になってるソフト上ではバックスラッシュが入力されてしまうようです。

その判断は正しいのでしょうか？むしろ、ターミナルとiTermのみの挙動と、私は推測します。こういうことは、統計学的にとまではいいませんが、相当数のサンプルをピックアップしてから、結論を出さなくてはいけないと思います。
話の発端の「RubyMine」では、どうなんですか？

Comment: そうですね、早計でした。RubyMine上ではGoogle IME上では設定にかかわらずoptionありでバックスラッシュが、optionなしなら円記号が入力されるようです。